# Menú con imagenes en WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menú

Tengo un menú que debo crear con aproximadamente 30 items con su respectivo hover, al pararme en cada item se visualiza otra imagen en el menu.

La idea es que necesito hacer administrable esto, ejemplo :

```
Menú >>

>>Link item menu 1

>>Cargar Imagen item 1

>>Cargar Imagen Hover Item 1

>>Link item menu n

>>Cargar Imagen item n

>>Cargar Imagen Hover Item n
```

No sé cual sea la mejor forma de hacerlo , con Menu Walker ? Con el Plugin ACF de WP ?

Debido a que son muchos items (menu carrusel) quisiera lo más practico para administrar esto.

Agradezco ideas.

Comment: Te recomiendo que preguntes dentro de https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Allí creo que te pueden asesorar mucho mejor ;)

Comment: Primero hazlo estático. Luego intenta tus alternativas. A continuación elige la que te parezca que cumple con tus expectativas. Si tienes algún problema real y concreto, entonces puedes preguntar aquí, incluyendo el respectivo [mcve]. Recuerda que las preguntas que piden opiniones, recomendaciones, ideas o que son demasiado abiertas, deben ser cerradas.